# Upload video to YouTube Data API v3 without using the Java Client Library

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

I'm developing a service to upload videos to YouTube and I got it working on V2, but I'm migrating to V3 but I can't find REST endpoints to hit.

The Resumable Upload is [well docummented here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol) but the Direct Upload is only documented as [a Python script reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video).

My process can't support Resumable Uploads and I can't use the Java Client Library because I don't have the files stored locally. For V2 I used a different approach that allowed me to do piping.

Is there a way to do this on V3???

```
String lineEnd = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";

String access_token = "A1S2D3F4G5H6J7K8L9";
String gameClipID = "gameClipID";
String sourceServerURL = "sourceServerURL";

String boundary = "Boundary" + gameClipID;
String closingBoundary = lineEnd + twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens;

URL youTubeURL = new URL("http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads");
HttpURLConnection youTubeConnection = (HttpURLConnection)youTubeURL.openConnection();
youTubeConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
youTubeConnection.setDoOutput(true);
youTubeConnection.setDoInput(true);

// Set Headers
youTubeConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization" , "GoogleLogin auth=" + auth);
youTubeConnection.setRequestProperty("GData-Version", "2");
youTubeConnection.setRequestProperty("X-GData-Key", "key=" + developerKey);
youTubeConnection.setRequestProperty("Slug", gameClipID);
youTubeConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
youTubeConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
youTubeConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/related;boundary=" + boundary);

String content = prepareContent(boundary, "Title", "Description", keywords);
Long totalLength = (long)content.length() + (long)fileSize + (long)closingBoundary.length();

youTubeConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", totalLength.toString());
youTubeConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");

URL sourceURL = new URL(sourceServerURL);
HttpURLConnection sourceConnection = (HttpURLConnection) sourceURL.openConnection();
sourceConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
sourceConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", access_token);
sourceConnection.connect();

BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(sourceConnection.getInputStream());

BufferedOutputStream request = new BufferedOutputStream(youTubeConnection.getOutputStream());

request.write(content.getBytes("UTF-8"));

boolean eof = false;
byte[] input = new byte[4096];
while (!eof) {
    int length = bis.read(input);
    if (length == -1) {
        eof = true;
    } else {
        request.write(input, 0, length);
    }
}

request.write(closingBoundary.getBytes("UTF-8"));
request.flush();
request.close();
bis.close();
sourceConnection.disconnect();

InputStream responseStream = new BufferedInputStream(youTubeConnection.getInputStream());
BufferedReader responseStreamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));

String line;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = responseStreamReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(line);
}
responseStreamReader.close();

String response = stringBuilder.toString();
responseStream.close();
youTubeConnection.disconnect();

return YouTubeClient.parseXMLResponse(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Direct upload equivalent of the documentation, would be just setting uploadType=direct.

You can set directUploadEnabled to true in this example and see the Post request to make sure.
https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/UploadVideo.java#L136

Also here's the source code of the directUpload so you can build this manually.
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/google-api-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/googleapis/media/MediaHttpUploader.java#345

Comment: This is still using the Java Client API, and that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I asked you to, just create a demo with it and find the post request. So that you can build your manual post request with same options. Also updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and I'll vote after I find a suitable solution.